# BLE only getting Battery Level characteristic Value IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to read all the services available and their characteristics value using CoreBluetooth framework from a device.

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
        advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
        NSLog(@"Received peripheral : \n%@", peripheral);
        NSLog(@"Adv data : %@", advertisementData);

    self.activeperipheral=peripheral;

    [self.myCentralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];

    if(peripheral.state==CBPeripheralStateConnected){
        peripheral.delegate=self;
        NSLog(@"Connected");

    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Not Connected");

    NSArray *serviceUUIDs=[advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey];
    for(CBUUID *foundserviceUUIDs in serviceUUIDs){

        if([serviceUUIDs containsObject:foundserviceUUIDs]){
            NSLog(@"%@",serviceUUIDs);
        }
    }

}

-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error{

    for(CBService *service in peripheral.services){
    [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];
        NSLog(@"Discover Service:%@",service);
    }
}

-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error{

    for(CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics){
        [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
        self.myCharacteristic=characteristic;
        NSLog(@"NotifyValue set on %@",characteristic);
        //[peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:myCharacteristic];

    }
}


-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error{
if(characteristic.isNotifying)
    NSLog(@"Notification began on %@",characteristic);
}


-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error  {

    NSLog(@"%@",characteristic);
   // NSLog(@"Characteristic Value Updated");
}

- (int)scanForPeripherals {
    NSLog(@"Scanning");

    if(self.myCentralManager.state!=CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)
        NSLog(@"Turn on Bluetooth");
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey,
                             nil];
    NSLog(@"Scanning");
    [myCentralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];
    return 0;
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
    NSLog(@"Peripheral Connected");
    peripheral.delegate=self;
    //CBUUID *serviceUUID=[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1804"];
    [peripheral discoverServices:nil];
    //[myCentralManager stopScan];
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didDisconnectPeripheral");
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didFailToConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"failed to connect");
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didReadRSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didReadRSSI");
}

@end
```

The problem is I cannot setNotifyValue : Yes for other characteristics except the BatteryLevel characteristic and I am also getting the notification for the same only.

[image: Output]

Here is my output.
Any idea what am I doing wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: You can only get notification for characteristics if they indeed allow it. See their properties with the `CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify`. Else, you have to read the value. In other words: `if (characteristic & CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify){//setNotifyValue}else {[peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:characteristic]}`

Comment: @Larme I did edit the code and used readValueForCharacteristic function but didUpdateValueForCharacteristic is being called for only BatteryLevel characteristic!

Answer (score 0):

That because your characteristic settings in gatt file (your bluetooth project) is not properly setup. See for example another characteristic settings and update your gatt file. 
Another way to get characteristic value use a timer in which read your charackteristic:

```
   -(void)TimerFunction
    {
      [talking_peripher readValueForCharacteristic:_talk_charack];
      NSlog("VALUE: %@" _talk_charack);
    }
```

And that is all. But actually best to do -  modify your characteristic settings in gatt file (bluetooth project).

Answer (score 0):

There’s no error, except for the fact that you can set notification flag only for characteristics that support the property “notify” from all available characteristic properties (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcharacteristicproperties).

U can check which properties a specific characteristic support when u run into:

```
optional func peripheral(
    _ peripheral: CBPeripheral,
    didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService,
    error: Error?
)
```

Then checking for CBCharacteristic.properties value by iterating the returned service.characteristics property (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbservice)

In your code when u loop into characteristics you should first check if current characteristic support CBCharactirsticProperties.notify before u call func “setNotifyValue:YES”